# Can we include () in step definiton of cucumber?

Tags: cucumber-jvm

I have a step defined in stepdefinition.java which is

```
@And(^I wait for \"(.*?)\" min$)
```

Can we define it as

```
@And(^I wait for \"(.*?)\" min(s)$)
```

Comment: Hi Amlesh! Does the answer help you to solve the issue?

Comment: Yes,It helped me.Thanks

Comment: So in that case, maybe you could mark the answer as accepted, to help other people. Thanks and glad to help you

Answer (score 3):

As it's described in [this post](https://softnoise.wordpress.com/2012/10/07/escaping-fun-replaceall/), you need to escape the parenthesis with double backquote `\\`

So, your step definition should be like this:

```
@And("^I wait for \"(.*?)\" min\\(s\\)$")
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Just for the case someone is looking for a solution working with data types on newer versions (from cucumber 4.3.0), you only have to escape the opening bracket like this:

```
@Then("Waehle die Option {string} \\(ersetze {string} mit {string}) in der Mehrfachauswahlliste {string}")
```